# Realizing an XOR expression using NAND gates

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, boolean-algebra, nand

I've been trying really hard to understand the construction of a logical circuit using only NAND while *also* trying to minimize the number of gates. The minimization of gates is what is really confusing me, so my thought process is like so.

```
1) Start with the desired expression of the end
2) Work backwards with the understanding that the output(s) were also derived from a NAND
3) Run intermediate expression through K-Map to get most simplified form
4) Attempt to convert to an AND if it isn't already using DeMorgans law 
5) Rinse and repeat steps 2-5
```

I attempted this approach with XOR using only NAND and did indeed get 4 gates, but it's different than ones I see online and just wanted to validate if it's correct or not and if not, where my errors are.

[image]

I'm worried that the first NAND where I feed the output into two separate gates isn't valid, so looking for some confirmation on that as well.

Thanks.

Comment: The output of your third from left NAND gate is always going to be 0, ignoring glitches.

Comment: A xor B = A./B + /A.B = /(/(A./B) . /(/A.B)) (De Morgan)

Comment: A xor B = /(A.B + /A./B) = /(A.B) . /(/A./B)

Comment: dang I didn't catch that. I'm more confused now on the simplification of the expressions. Is my boolean logic incorrect from an equivalence perspective between the last 2 gates?

Comment: The output of your 2nd from left NAND is, as you say, A B. But the output of the left most NAND is, as you say, (A B)'. If A B is true, then (A B)' must be false -- and visa versa. So the inputs to the third from left NAND must always be opposite each other. So that 3rd from left NAND will always output 1. The final output will always be 0.

Comment: @jonk because I am working backward -> right to left, to yield the construction of the gate, is the conversion from the right-most and the gate right before it incorrect?

Comment: @Ryan If your starting point is the right-most equation, then yes that's an XOR. However, I don't see how you arrived at the equation just to the left of it.

Comment: let me rewrite logic steps and I will post an image --thanks!

Comment: @jonk My thought process is that the input to the last NAND is ultimately just the negation of (a' + b')(a + b), is that a valid statement? Since the NAND will negate it again to yield that input. Therefore, I attempted to simplify ((a' + b')(a + b))'

Comment: @Ryan (a' + b')(a + b) = (((a' + b')(a + b))')' = ((a' + b')' + (a + b)')' = ((a b) + (a' b'))'. Does that make sense?

Comment: If I'm working backward, would I want to first negate that to visualize what the input would be to the last NAND? i.e ((a' + b')(a + b))`

Comment: so I got it, but unfortunately, still yielding 5 gates because of the NOT inverter.. I can't seem to figure out how to avoid that

Comment: This may address your question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43342/how-to-construct-xor-gate-using-only-4-nand-gate The key is, these realizations identify a sub-expression ~(a&b) that's used twice.

Comment: Although most people who have spent much time studying the topic have gone through the process of minimizing an XOR expression using only NAND or NOR, it is ironic that the automated tool, Espresso, won't find this minimum realization on its own.